# Token id for GCM(Google cloud messaging) for push notifications

Tags: android

Is there any token id, that should be provided to the server side.

What are the things that should be provided to the server side for making the api url.

After registering in Google console i got this..

Key for server apps (with IP locking)
API key:

---

IPs:
Any IP allowed

and

Key for browser apps (with referers)
API key:

---

Referers:
Any referer allowed

Is it enough or i have to do anything else.

Comment: Your device registration id is your token id. When you register your device for receive GCM responce the GCM server returns a registration id of your device. you have to store this id to your server for send notification to this device in future. look at this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html) for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will set headers of your request  with parameter  authorization : key="api access key" that given by google console when you had saved project for GCM .

Comment: Simple API Access
Use API keys to identify your project when you do not need to access user data. Learn more
Key for server apps (with IP locking)
API key: 
***********************************
IPs: 
Any IP allowed

Generate new key...
Edit allowed IPs...
Delete key...
Key for browser apps (with referers)
API key: 
*****************************
Referers: 
Any referer allowed



I got these key